# GPU SMD Capacitors Leaking?

Tags: gpu

This is odd, but it almost seems like the surface mount capacitors are leaking on my old EVGA GTX 970.  Is this common?  I have no problem using my rework station on these, but I've never seen SMD caps leak.

There is an odd residue surrounding only the caps

[image: Overview]
[image: Puddling]

Comment: As Mokubai says, they are [MLCC (Multi-Layer Ceramic Capacitors)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_capacitor#Multi-layer_ceramic_capacitors_(MLCC)) and can't "_leak_"... I'd suggest that looks a lot like a burnt / scorched PCB, and the significant stitching / vias in the area suggest there is a thermal consideration in the design... Can you take a better picture? Is the card stable?

Comment: It is stable, I'm going to alcohol wash them.  Just very odd.

Answer (score 1):

They are not leaking. There is nothing to leak from those capacitors.

It looks simply to be dust that has accumulated against the capacitors due to them being in the airflow path in the case.

---

To be clear, those are ceramic capacitors. Essentially they are metal plates suspended in a ceramic resin. There is nothing to leak as they are dry.  If they are indeed leaking then you would see them glowing white hot under operation.

It is possible that you could be seeing some leftover flux from the initial soldering procedure which now has dust embedded in it, but it is not harmful nor is it going to significantly affect the capacitors.

Comment: I've added another picture to the post.  Flux fits the bill, but I just don't remember ever seeing it before.